# Блокировка Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, async-await, блокировки

Читаю Рихтера и наткнулся на интересное ограничение асинхронной операции

> Не допускается установление блокировки, поддерживающей владение потоком или рекурсию, до операции `await`, и ее снятие после оператора `await`. Это ограничение объясняется тем, что один поток может выполнить код до `await`,
>   а другой поток может выполнить код после `await`. При использовании `await`
>   с командой С# `lock` компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке. Если вместо
>   этого явно вызвать методы `Enter` и `Exit` класса `Monitor`, то код откомнилиру-

почему не допускается блокировка await это и есть deadlock???

Comment: цитату стоит переписать ручками, так как картинка не индексируется поисковиками.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала простой пример:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Выполнив его, вы увидите 2 разных значения. Это значит, что код после оператора `await` может выполнятся в другом потоке, нежели код до оператора.

Теперь попробуем сделать то, про что пишет Рихтер:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var syncObject = new object();

    Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
    await Task.Yield();
    Monitor.Exit(syncObject);
}
```

Получим `SynchronizationLockException`. Что бы понять почему так происходит, нужно знать как работает `Monitor.Enter` (ну и оператор `lock` соответственно).

Когда выполняется метод `Monitor.Enter`, CLR запоминает текущий поток в заголовке объекта (managed object header). Мы можем несколько раз вызывать `Monitor.Enter` на одном и том же объекте в одном и том же потоке, и мы не будем получать блокировок. Код ниже отработает моментально:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var syncObject = new object();
    Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
    Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
    Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
}
```

Когда вызывается метод `Monitor.Exit`, CLR проверяет, совпадает ли поток, который заблокировал объект, с потоком, который пытается разблокировать объект. Эта проверка как раз и гарантирует то, что только один поток может выполнять код в блоке `lock (obj) { ... }`.

Что бы исключить внезапный `SynchronizationLockException` и ввели ошибку компиляции связанную с операторами `await` и `lock`. Это не связано с дедлоками.

Comment: Можете порекомендовать литературу на эту тему? По Task и asynk/await, именно то, что собой представляет пул потоков, как они извлекаются, выполняются, возвращаются?

Comment: @AlexanderBrattsev извините, не могу ничего порекомендовать, в последние время учусь только по блогам и ответам на стековерфлов

Comment: @AlexanderBrattsev вот  [этот блог](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) и вот [эта книга](https://csharpindepth.com/) дадут вам 90% того, что надо знать.

Comment: просто отмечу, что, несмотря на то, что ответ на 50% правильный, он имеет некоторые оговорки. Например, выбор потока, в котором может выполняться продолжение, сильно зависит от текущего контекста синхронизации (потому в UI потоке продолжение будет в том же UI потоке). Но если текущего контекста нет, то продолжение будет работать в любом доступном потоке из пула, и, есть вероятность, что опять оно будет в том де потоке, где было начало. Чтобы этим хоть как от управлять, существует ConfigureAwait, но это имхо уже за пределами ответа, иначе пришлось бы целую статью писать об async\await

Comment: @tym32167 почему ответ на 50% верный, если я написал "код после оператора await **может** выполнятся в другом потоке". Может в другом, а может и нет :)

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за литературу. Полезная. Отличная аналогия про заказ пиццы в книге. Синхронно: заказал пиццу по телефону, и ждешь у двери, асинхронно: заказал пиццу по телефону, и пока её нет, отдыхаешь или делаешь что то другое =)

Comment: @Zergatul сорри, не так выразился. Имел ввиду, что в ответе только половина инфы раскрыта и есть ещё другая половина - не раскрытая.

Answer (score 1):

Дедлок- это когда поток 1 владеет ресурсом А и ждет, когда освободится ресурс Б, которым владеет поток 2, а тот в свою очередь ждет ресурс А, которым владеет поток 1. Круг замкнулся.

Фишка `await` в том, что до встречи `await` код может быть выполнен одним потоком, а после `await` продолжить выполнение в другом.

Из этого следует то, что другой поток попросту не сможет войти в блок синхронизации, так как им владеет другой поток.

Если рассмотреть то, во что компилируется этот синтаксический сахар в виде async/await, то такое ограничение станет еще более понятным.

Попросту, это все компилируется в конечный автомат из `switch/case`, где в некоторую переменную заносится флаг того, что такой-то код выполнен. Натыкаясь на `await`, происходит выход из метода и возвращение потока в пул. Когда задача выполнена, то этот метод снова дергается(возможно уже в другом потоке из пула) и на основании флага пропускаются этапы, которые ранее были выполнены и продолжается синхронная работа метода.

А теперь подумайте, как оно будет работать с `lock'ом`.